# Correct way of downloading a file with POST data using WebClient

Tags: c#, download, webclient

I currently have an app that posts data to a web server, then downloads the response. I use `UploadDataAsync` to achieve the result, using the following:

```
        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            var dataToPost = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(postBody);

            client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization, authToken); // Add the authorization header

            client.UploadDataCompleted += UploadCompleteCallback; // What do do when the download completes
            client.UploadProgressChanged += UploadProgressCallback; // What to do when the download is in progress

            client.UploadDataAsync(uri, "POST", dataToPost);

            while (client.IsBusy)
            {
                // We're going to wait until the operation completes
            }
        }
```

It does successfully download the file, however I'm wondering if it's the correct way, because I'm not using `DownloadDataAsync`.

The reason I'm not is because I can't find a way to send my POST data with the `DownloadDataAsync` method.

Additionally, the `UploadProgressCallback` only gets called once when the app starts, then waits a while, and get's called again basically when the file is finished (So not a fluid download progress indicator). Is this possibly because I've used the `upload` instead of `download` ?

**For completness** here is my `UploadProgressCallback`:

```
    private static void UploadProgressCallback(object sender, UploadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Displays the operation identifier, and the transfer progress.
        Console.WriteLine("{0} Downloaded {1} of {2} bytes. {3} % complete...",
            (string)e.UserState,
            e.BytesReceived,
            e.TotalBytesToReceive,
            e.ProgressPercentage);
    }
```